# Test suite failed to run Your test suite must contain at least one test.

Tags: webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, jestjs

Im getting this error

Test suite failed to run

```
Your test suite must contain at least one test.

  at node_modules/jest-cli/build/test_scheduler.js:108:22
```

with jest configuration

```
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      ".*": "./tests/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "modulePaths": [
      "src"
    ],
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/",
    "/vendor"
  ],
  "testRegex": "\\.spec\\.js"
  }
```

any help how can i solve this
im i missing something

thanks in advance
carlos vieira

Comment: Can you share the file where it threw this error?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is happening because you have created the test file, but not included any of the tests.
example:- The below unit test consists of only describe part not covering any tests (commented as of now)

```
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import React from "react";
import Privileges from "./privileges";

describe("Privileges Component ", () => {
    //const wrapper = mount(<Privileges />).find(".privileges-container");
    
    // it("should render in DOM", () => {

    //     expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
    // });

    
});
```

[image]